# May JSON-LD values have varying types?

Tags: json, json-ld

Is it allowed that a particular value of my JSON-LD format may have varying types? E.g., I want to allow both

```
{
  "@context":"example.org/context.jsonld",
  "attr":"pubDate",
  "value":1998
}
```

and

```
{
  "@context":"example.org/context.jsonld",
  "attr":"author",
  "value":"Smith"
}
```

Here, `value` is once an integer, once a string. Generally, can the value possibly be of any type (also lists, objects,...)?

If so, how do I define the `@type` alternatives in the `@context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using `attr` and `value` to form your kind of own triple (i.e. `this object` has `attr` `value`). But the whole point of JSON-LD is that you can express RDF-triples. For example using [Dublin Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core):

```
{
    "@context": {
        "pubDate": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/date",
        "author": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator"
    },
    "pubDate": 1988,
    "author": "Smith"
}
```

Of course, if you have to cater to legacy applications you can always leave in additional values that are not interpreted as RDF.

```
{
    "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/date", 1988,
    "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator": "Smith",
    "legacy-attributes": [
        {
            "attr":"pubDate",
            "value": 1988
        },
        {
            "attr":"author",
            "value":"Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```